onkeyup Event does not fire in a Blazor Web App but does fire in a Blazor Server App
When I run the below code in a Blazor Server App the code executes as expected.  However, when I run the same code in a Blazor Web App, execution never enters the ReverseText Method.  In the Blazor Web App I selected Interactive Render Mode => Server just to ensure that was not the cause.
Is there an explanation why the code executes in the Blazor Server App but not in the Blazor Web App?
Thank you
 @page "/"

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name">Contact: </label>
    <input type="text" @bind="strInput" @onkeyup="ReverseText" />
</div>

<p>Reversed: @strRevInput</p>

@code {
    private string strInput = "";
    private string strRevInput = "Rev";

    private void ReverseText()
    {
        strRevInput = ReverseString(strInput);
    }

    private string ReverseString(string input)
    {
        char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
}



I'm guessing you selected Interactivity location as Per Page/Component.
If you want full Blazor Server functionality, create a solution using the Blazor Web App template and select

Interactivity => InteractiveServer
Interactivity location => Global


After my test, I also created a Blazor web app and selected server mode in the  Interactive Render Mode  selection. After the project is created, you need to configure the corresponding rendering mode to InteractiveServer.
If you choose to render for the page when creating the per page, the component will use static server-side rendering (static SSR). The component is rendered to the response stream and interactivity is not enabled.
So you can use @rendermode InteractiveServer to configure the rendering mode to InteractiveServer.
For example:

@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name">Contact: </label>
    <input type="text" @bind="strInput" @onkeyup="ReverseText" />
</div>

<p>Reversed: @strRevInput</p>

@code {
    private string strInput = "";
    private string strRevInput = "Rev";

    private void ReverseText()
    {
        strRevInput = ReverseString(strInput);
    }

    private string ReverseString(string input)
    {
        char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
}


If you use global rendering, you don’t need additional configuration. By default, the rendering mode will be configured to InteractiveServer. In the configuration of app.razor, you can see
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> and <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
This will be assigned to the InteractiveServer rendering mode of the entire application.
Example:

Components:
@page "/"

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name">Contact: </label>
    <input type="text" @bind="strInput" @onkeyup="ReverseText" />
</div>

<p>Reversed: @strRevInput</p>

@code {
    private string strInput = "";
    private string strRevInput = "Rev";

    private void ReverseText()
    {
        strRevInput = ReverseString(strInput);
    }

    private string ReverseString(string input)
    {
        char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
}


For more information about rendering mode configuration, you can refer to this document.

Excellent Yuning!  Thank you.   I would like to ask a follow up question.  If I create a Blazor Web App with Interactive Render Mode Server Global is that equivalent to creating a Blazor Server App?  Thank you
